# Can objects drawn in canvas response to mouse events?

Tags: html, canvas, mouseover

can I make objects drawn in canvas response to mouse events? for example, to change colors or to display toolips on mouseover? I can adjust some values by using other types of inputs (range, radio...), but cannot make direct mouse manipulation on objects drawn in canvas.

Comment: What like this http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/JS/html5_canvas_mouse_events.html?

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to make each graphic elements respond to mouseover instead of an entire canvas. e.g., different segments of pie chart drawn in one canvas... is it possible?

Comment: This is one of the reasons why SVG can be a better solution for charting vs. Canvas as each element can handle mouse events. I can highly recommend the Raphael library http://raphaeljs.com/ to generate SVG content (that fallsback to VML for old IE browsers) in fact there is even a charting library built on top of it http://g.raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Anything drawn on html canvas becomes unremembered pixels.

What you will need to do is "remember" everything about all the things you've drawn: shape, position, color.

Then you can respond to mouse events and compare the mouse position with the bounding boxes of your remembered drawings.

If you want to change any drawing (recolor, reposition, etc), you must redraw that drawing.

Most often when you redraw any one thing, you will erase the entire canvas and redraw all items that were on the canvas.

Answer (score 2):

You can listen for mouse events on the canvas.  The rest is up to you.  If you keep a list of objects drawn on the canvas, you can scan through the list looking for one that is under the mouse.